# How to install containerd on Debian?

Tags: kubernetes, debian

As the docker daemon gets deprecated in the future Kubernetes version 1.20, I just wanted to start a test installation of a kubernetes cluster with [containerd](https://containerd.io).
I am trying to install a new cluster running on a debian (buster) using [containerd](https://containerd.io) as the container runtime.

But it looks to me like containerd is supported for Ubuntu but not for debian? I did not found any solution or install guide how to install containerd as the container runtime on a debian node. Can this be true? Does anybody know how to install containerd on Debian ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install containerd
```

Docker use containerd that's why the package is available on its repositories.

Alternative method to install `containerd` by building the package from source: [Build containerd from source](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/BUILDING.md#build-containerd-from-source)

[Documentation and docker repository info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)

Comment: yes - that worked! But why is the package source from docker.com and not from containerd.io ?